# channel:form is deleting data not included in the channel form

Tags: safecracker, grid

There is an issue with channel:form, it is deleting data it should not. The following channel entry form will delete all grid entries I have for  product_images. The grid_entry field is product_images, and there are two columns called image and image_alt.

Yet using this code (notice I am not editing the grid field product_images that is being deleted), the grid field will be blank after saving, and no other field will be affected, just this grid field used for images.

```
{exp:channel:form channel="products" return="product" entry_id="801" include_jquery="no" include_assets="no"}

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">

{/exp:channel:form}
```

I have other grid fields for the entry that are not deleted, and I have a File field that is not deleted. So its either something to do with this specific field, or to do with the Grid field that has a File field in it.

Using EE 2.7.2

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug, a fix for EE 2.7 is here https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19772/, and an upgrade to 2.9 fixed it for me.